# How do I align the render of this page with bootstrap4 using visual studio

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm using visual studio 2019 and bootstrap4 (which I'm new to) to develop a web page for account registration. The render does not seem right. I remove ASP tags from the code below. I use a combination of codes from www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4. Below is the code I tried.

```
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Country</span>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control"><option>1</option></select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Business Name</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name">
        </div>   
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    Street</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street, including Building number and Suite">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            City</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            State</span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control"><option>1</option></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            Zip code</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip code"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            Telephone</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone">
                </div>  
            </div>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            Email Address</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            Website</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The input fields do not properly align. Can anyone help why the render does not properly align?

Comment: What is the current result and what is the expected result? But the very first div block does not have a row/col system...

Comment: The width of the input fields is not consistent. It does not always go up to the limit of the row. E.g. for the last "row", the input has the same width for the first 2 columns, but it is very tiny like 10% for the last one. I don't know how to post a pic here yet.

Comment: You are clearly not using the same bootstrap classes form-inline and row does not render the same way. You have 3 rows, the first renders together but the last two are the same. so what type of form arrangement do you intend to achieve?. Also you are not using labels for your form name

Comment: @Bosco
I've reviewed the code and came up with this, but I'm still not satisfied with the render. I'd like the input to be evenly distributed. For instance the last row should be as the second row, and the 4throw should be even. Code and snipped is at https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/jO6Db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the question and the comments it seems you are having trouble with `form-control` as it is not going up to its full width. That is because you have a custom css file in `Content` folder of your project structure that overrides the behavior of few tags. See:

[image]

Here you can see `input,select,textarea` tags have been overridden and you can just remove it or comment it out to make it go full width:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I also noticed that your html for input controls is also incorrect and not well formatted. Here is the correct version of it:

```
<style>
    .input-group {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Country</span>
                        </div>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Business Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Street</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street, including Building number and Suite">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">City</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">State</span>
                        </div>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Zip code</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip code">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Telephone</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Email Address</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Website</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[See the output here.](https://codepen.io/Jamsshhayd/pen/byKXvB)

Comment: Thanks for you help. You've help me solve this headache!

Comment: But here is the final layout I wanted with some glitches for the dropdown list https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/jO6Db.